# Should I attend Seminars/Conferences that give Certificates upon achieving some number of attendance?

Tags: conference, undergraduate, seminars, certification

The question is self-explanatory actually.

Should I attend Seminars/Conferences that give Certificates upon achieving some number of attendance? And do they have any worth if I/ to put them in my CV?

I'm an undergraduate student currently in Electrical-Electronical Engineering program and every week there are seminars carried out by University/Department and varius events carried out by various clubs. Some of them give certificate upon attandance and some of them require attending the seminar for some number of sessions for certification but I'm not sure if those certificate have any value at all and I want to know if it's worth ditching relaxing after week of lectures for some certificate that can be obtained by literally every single human being that walks in to the hall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the seminars/conferences on topics applicable to you? Do they interest you? Do you want more knowledge that can make you more competitive or are you just trying to make your CV look pretty?

Comment: My first goal is to make my CV look more pretty but at the same time more interesting to employer. Of course I have topics that I'm interested in and things I want to do/be able to do. But what's the point if I'm going to be unemployed, right? If having a 2-3 _certificates of **attendance**_ is going to make a difference, I'm willing to spend a day or two for that. Besides, seminars/event that give certificates are about more general topics about _enginneering and/or management_. An example topic of a 45 min. seminar: _Technology and Entrepreneurship_.

Comment: I never understand why people go to seminars because of certificates... Personally, I tend to dislike such behaviour and I don't employ those people. On hte other hand, I love it if people are interested in a topic and they go an extra mile. It's up to you to find the right balance!

Answer (score 1):

There is some value in attending these Seminars/Conferences that you may want to consider:

- It shows that you are "doing more" than the minimum requirements
- You may end up adding or emphasizing important keywords in your CV
- The Seminars/Conferences you mentioned are from University/Departments and clubs.  If the Seminars/Conferences have any "Name Brand" involvement, such as corporations or other institutions, you get the name of the institution on your CV.

Answer (score 0):

I am not in the same field, but I have never heard of something like this before. I would not worry about the certificates, and not put them on your CV.

My guess is that these are not certificates in the sense of 'something to show off and be proud of', but rather evidence of attendance for graduate students who are required to attend a certain number of seminars as part of their course requirements.

For an undergraduate, attending such seminars would be something you write about in your statement of purpose (or similar) when applying for graduate courses, as demonstrating your active interest in more advanced study. A local weekly seminar would not be significant enough to list on your CV, but a major conference might be worth listing, even if it happened to be taking place locally. As you continue through an academic career, this would drop off in favour of talks you have given, not just listened to. It is very unlikely that anyone outside academia would take much interest, except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: Just thinking... one difference would be if these are *skills based* training sessions, rather than research talks. For example, having attended a disability awareness session would be something that everyone in the room would get recognition for, although the value of that recognition would be very context dependent.

Answer (score -4):

Building a proffessional profile of yourself the more that you are attending Seminars/Conferences Meetings and Discutions it shows better reputations onbyour Profile Interviews 
PhD Sam Beljuli